# What is difference between Intel x86 atom system image vs Google APIs (x86 system image)

Tags: android

In Android SDK manager, under Android 4.4.2 (API 19) package, there are two images: `Intel x86 Atom System Image`, as well as `Google APIs (x86 System Image)` I am wondering, what the difference between those two images is?

I'm working on Windows 7, using Android Studio and have `Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator(HAXM)` installed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between Google APIs (x86 System Image) and Google APIs (ARM System Image) in Android 4.4.2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23416448/difference-between-google-apis-x86-system-image-and-google-apis-arm-system-im)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

> what is the difference between those two images ?

The Google APIs one has Google Maps and the Play Services framework in it.

Comment: Are there any significant emulation speed differences ?

Comment: @newprint: Not that I am aware of.