# What happened to Android 4.4.2 (API 19) Google APIs?

Tags: android, google-api

I am opening up an older android project on a new machine. I am attempting to download the Android 4.4.2 (API 19) Google APIs, but they are not listed. I have the regular SDK Platform installed. I do see Google API system images for the emulator, but not the actual Google API itself.

I see Google APIs in the Android 5.1.1 (API 22), as well as APIs older than 4.4.2 (API 19).
[image]

Am I missing something? If they were removed for some reason, what should my application be targeting?

I require Google APIs becuase my app is using Google Maps.

Edit: I even enabled Obsolete listings, to see if the Google APIs were obsolete for some reason, but they didn't show then, either.

Comment: Check the top answer from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23416448/difference-between-google-apis-x86-system-image-and-google-apis-arm-system-im

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are there. They are just available in two different flavors: `Google APIs (x86 System Image)` and `Google APIs (ARM System Image)`

Comment: Oh, I think I get it. They're different sets of APIs depending on the system image, as opposed to an actual system image. I guess that explains the different icon usage. Still curious though as to why there are 2 different sets, while the other APIs appear to just have one.