# Android SDK - Installing system images?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new to Android development. In Android Studio, I just installed every SDK under SDK Platforms. I noticed, though, when I click Show Package Details, that there are various System Images under each SDK version, called ARM EABI or Intel x86 Atom or Intel x86 Atom_64, and then the same things I just mentioned but with "Google APIs" prefix.

Is it good practice to install all of the images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call it a good or bad practice to install it or not doing it, it will depend on your needs (your machine hardware). If you use a device to compile, you can forget about those images.

Comment: As I said it will depend on your hardware, also Google APIs images is for supporting the Google APIs in your image.

Check more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23416448/difference-between-google-apis-x86-system-image-and-google-apis-arm-system-im

Answer (score 0):

Only install images when you need to test your application and what you need to test tell you what image need to be download.

Comment: So you can tell it to test and it'll let you know which one you need?

Comment: no, what i mean is download the images following the performance of your application