# Intellij IDEA Android preview doesn't work

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-sdk-manager

*Screenshot of the problem:*

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

*Android SDK packages have been downloaded:*

[image: Android SDK packages have been downloaded]

Edited@2016/10/09:

What are the uses of system image? Are these related to my question?

Comment: Where is the description of your problem? This is too broad.

Comment: I'd like to mention that you don't need to install every last thing in the SDK Manager. You should only download the system image for the architecture of your machine

Comment: To @cricket_007: Do you mean that the "Sources for Android SDK" is unnecessary? My CPU is Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4210U, what system image should I choose. btw, thanks for your helping again.

Comment: The Intel x86 one, assuming you've also installed Intel HAXM

Comment: To @cricket_007: I noticed that there is a Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System image too. what's the difference between them? I should keep or uninstalled that one?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23416448/difference-between-google-apis-x86-system-image-and-google-apis-arm-system-im

Answer (score 4, accepted):

that's because you updating your sdk into 24 api and your android studio cannot display and preview that level , you should change your android version for rendering layouts in the IDE to 23 like this image ...
[image]

Comment: "... your android studio cannot display and preview that level, " could this be a problem to be solved(like after downloading some files needed), or this be  a problem from API 24 itself?

Comment: maybe this problem be solved by updating android studio to final stable version.