# Can anyone tell me which item is to install or which item is not need to install for my xamarin android apps?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

[Here is the screenshot of the Android SDK Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9FBf.png)

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/windows/manual_installation/#Install_Android_SDK

Answer (score 0):

Install latest android sdk tools, platform tools, and build tools, as in below screenshot

[image]

and only install latest sdk platform or sdk platform that you wanna target, no need to install everything that is checked.

Comment: i asked for which is to install, APIs Intel x86 Atom 64 System image or APIs Intel x86 Atom System image or APIs ARM 64 v8a System image or APIs ARM EABI v7a System image ?????

Comment: Arm system image is bit slower as compared to x86 system image and Google Api system image is used for support of google specific API like Google maps API, more info in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24817495/5611425)