# Difference between Google API intel x86 atom and Google Play intel x86 atom sytem image

Tags: android

While downloading Android 8.0 sdk platform using Android Studio, I see these two system images.

1. Google API intel x86 atom system image
2. Google Play intel x86 atom sytem image

What is the difference between these two?.

Comment: IIRC, the second one comes with the Play Store and Google proprietary apps, but has significant restrictions (e.g., no root access).

Comment: With Google Play intel x86 atom sytem image , we will have play store and will be able to install apps on emulator?

Answer (score 65):

The play image has the Google Play store already installed and you can install apps, but there is no root access as it is a production build and not a debug build.

Comment: what is the disadvantage for a developer that there is no root access? why do I need it?

Comment: I couldn't turn Debug on Play image (#2) neither I could run & deeploy app via Android studio to instance based on Play image (#2)

Comment: but why I can't choose it, in AVD only Google APIs are available for emulators, I already downloaded Google Play image using SDK manager but it's not visible in ADV Manager...

Comment: Does it mean the other ones has Google Play installed too but **with** root access?!

Answer (score 20):

"Google APIs" images include the [Play services](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/packages) that many apps rely on but no Play Store app

"Google Play" images include both the Play Store app and the [Play services](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/packages)

For Google's description, see [Create and manage virtual devices | Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds#system-image)

Answer (score 17):

The main difference between Google API system image and Google Play system image basically lays on the capabilities of each one to access the Google Play Store directly or not. 
[Here is](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/67qcmw/google_play_system_images_android_studio_232_and/dgt1rzl/) for more explanation regarding that matter.

Hope, could be a helped for the other.

Answer (score 10):

What all answers are missing: If you use the billing library from Google, you *need* the "**Google Play image**" for testing. This has nothing to do with installing apps, but you need the Play Store installed to test your "in-app" purchases and subscription products.
Otherwise you will get this error from `BillingClient`:

```
Billing service unavailable on device
```

Answer (score 5):

Based on Documentation:

A system image labeled with Google APIs includes access to Google Play services. A system image labeled with the Google Play logo in the Play Store column includes the Google Play Store app and access to Google Play services, including a Google Play tab in the Extended controls dialog that provides a convenient button for updating Google Play services on the device.

To ensure app security and a consistent experience with physical devices, system images with the Google Play Store included are signed with a release key, which means that you cannot get elevated privileges (root) with these images. If you require elevated privileges (root) to aid with your app troubleshooting, you can use the Android Open Source Project (AOSP) system images that do not include Google apps or services.

I hope helped you.